# Must one take anticoagulants lifelong after stenting of deep veins with a non-thrombotic lesion?

Tags: medications, blood-circulation, cardiovascular-disease, venous-system, stents

Must one take anticoagulants lifelong after stenting of deep veins with a non-thrombotic lesion, for example, aorto-venous conflict ([May-Thurner syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May%E2%80%93Thurner_syndrome))?

Or is it enough to take anticoagulants only in the first 6 months, until the stent grows into the vein?

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00270-014-0875-4

> Platelet aggregation is known to be important in high-flow, high-shear
>   environment, such as in the coronary arteries, whereas coagulation may
>   be more important in the fibrin-rich thrombi characteristic of the
>   low-flow, low-shear venous circulation [42]. The relative importance
>   of antiplatelet agents versus anticoagulants has never been evaluated
>   in clinical trials and is largely based on extrapolation from the
>   arterial system and an understanding of the venous system. Based on
>   clinical data on stenting of chronic iliocaval occlusions, long-term
>   warfarin is recommended in patients with long occlusions, underlying
>   thrombophilia, suprarenal occlusions, and previous long-term
>   anticoagulation and poor inflow on completion angiogram [43, 44]. With
>   postthrombotic lesions being more prone to restenosis, the use of
>   anticoagulants appears to be useful in this subgroup. Thus, although
>   the use of antiplatelet agents and anticoagulants has not been studied
>   systematically, there seems to be a role for these drugs.

Comment: Are you asking what are the current guidelines or are you asking what should be done for a particular patient?

Comment: @CareyGregory I am asking what are the current guidelines.